# Where should I post a question about programming with software NOVA?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am using [NOVA](https://www.metrohm-autolab.com/NOVA2.html) (software used in electrochemistry), to do programming using blocks.

Which is the best community to ask questions about programming and measurement building with NOVA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, that looks remotely similar to LabVIEW. There are currently [1266 LabVIEW questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labview) on Stack Overflow, so that would be my place to try. Please make sure you read [their help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: Ok so Stack-overflow is the best option, since it is very simlar to LabVIEW, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are questions about [Nova](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-do-i-write-many-cyclic-voltammetry-curves-in-nova) on our site [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), and over [1500 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrochemistry) about Electrochemistry there.

From their Meta: "[What is the best site to ask computational questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3929/73620)" - Tyberius

> "From my understanding of the current guidelines here:

> If the question you are asking is directly related to the chemical/physical theory behind a calculation, it is perfectly fine to ask here.

> ...

> If your question is about a particular algorithm that is used in computational chemistry, but not directly related to chemical/physical theory (i.e. it's more of a chemistry-themed math/programming question than a Chemistry question), you may find someone who can answer the question here, but might be better off on Matter Modeling, Computational Science, or Math SE (probably in that order if it is commonly used in computational chemistry).".

Metrohm's Autolab [Nova is a drag and drop GUI](https://www.metrohm-autolab.com/Products/Echem/Software/NOVA_Editor.html) for **non-programmers** to build procedures.

Their [SDK](https://www.metrohm-autolab.com/Products/Echem/Software/SDK) is a completely different product for programmers, and not the same as Nova.